# Laravel 4 Auth wrong username or email error

Tags: php, laravel-4

i want to give the user a visual feedback if they entered wrong login information.

```
public function doLogin()
{
  $rules = array(
    'email'    => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|min:3'
  );

  $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

  if ($validator->fails()) {
    return Redirect::route('login')
      ->withErrors($validator)
      ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
  } else {
    $userdata = array(
      'email' => Input::get('email'),
      'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
      return Redirect::route('dashhome')
        ->withJsd('true');
    } else {
      return Redirect::route('login')
        ->withErrors(['wrongpw','Wrong E-mail address or Password']);
    }

  }
}
```

and on my login view i have this code

```
@if ($errors->has('wrongpw'))
  <script>
    $.gritter.add({
      title: 'Ups!',
      text: "{{ $errors->first('wrongpw') }}",
      class_name: 'warning',
      time: ''
    });
  </script>
@endif
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea what i make wrong or any suggestions on how to do it better?

Thanks

Comment: `ERROR_NOT_FOUND`. What exactly does not work? No redirection, wrong text?

Comment: Sry, forgot to mention. The @if ($errors->has('wrongpw')) does not get executed. so its always false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are not passing errors in a correct associative array,

try

```
->withErrors(array('wrongpw' => 'Wrong E-mail address or Password'));
```

or

```
->withErrors(['wrongpw' => 'Wrong E-mail address or Password']);
```